how do i set django up? and fix this error?
127.0.0.1/:1  Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/scripts/scripts.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
error i got...
how do i even fix this?
i have generated a template from django and they look messy so i want to organise files like .css files and pages files...
i tried to add my .css file and routed the html to use this .css. later i discovered that i gotta add
{% load static %} to load static files i have added this too and still not working....
this s the image guys
in the image i made a styles folder and wanted to use that but not the site.css file, i think i need to edit some things in the settings.py can you guys instruct me?

try adding <script ... type="text/javascript"> to your scripts in templates

Please add this to setting.py file and try again.
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type("text/javascript", ".js", True)

mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)


i have tried that it still not working i am getting the same error....

For http://127.0.0.1:8000/scripts/scripts.js:-
Could you try to visit the URL from your browser and check whether the file is loading? You can also debug through developer's tools in your browser, click F12, and go to the Network tab.
For styles.css:-
Could you add this to your settings.py file?
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

Now, if your file path is /static/somepath/styles.css
You can easily access the file with this.
{% load static %}

#your code
<a href="{% static 'somepath/styles.css' %}">Link</a>


this is what i am getting when i visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/scripts/scripts.js:-
image of js page
let me revise things up again...
this is what i have added in my html
this is site.css structure
i have added mime types screenshot in the settings.py
you can also check the static_url in it! @akbar-khan

You can use this, this might work. If not let me know, I will give a try by creating a scenario you are currently facing.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/content/site.css' %}">

For javascript:- You can debug through developer's tools in your browser, press F12, and go to the Network tab.
